# How to convert single element tuple into string?

Tags: python, string, tuples

I have this code:

```
 import nltk
 import pypyodbc

 text = raw_input()
 token = nltk.word_tokenize(text) //return a list value


def search(self, lists):
    if not self.connected:
        self.connect()
    for word in lists:
        self.cur.execute('SELECT Ybanag FROM Words WHERE English IN (%s)' % (','.join('?'*len(lists))), lists)
        result = self.cur.fetchall()
        return result
```

wherein the output is a list of single element tuple (ex. I enter `we all there`): 
      `[('tore',), ('ngaming',), ('sittam',)]` (translate the input into mother tongue language). I want that the output will be converted into string to eliminate the `[],(),'','` symbols. How to convert it into string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `str.join` method.

```
>>> a = [('tore',), ('ngaming',), ('sittam',)]
>>> " ".join([x[0] for x in a])
'tore ngaming sittam'
```

Comment: @TomByler, it works, you can select it as answer. That will help others to find correct answer.

Comment: Another question is how can I convert the single element tuple into an array or how to store the string into an array variable?

Comment: You can convert using `[x[0] for x in a]`

Comment: Yes, is that not the same like in single element tuple - string conversion? What if instead of string, the result in this line `result = self.cur.fetchall()` will be stored in an array variable? Can I do this `array[]=result`?

Comment: @TomByler, better to ask another question with full details.

Comment: Given the same example sir,  `a = [('tore',), ('ngaming',), ('sittam',)]`, from your codes, but this time will convert it into an array or maybe store the result of this `" ".join([x[0] for x in a])` into an array variable?

Comment: If you want to store in array means `list` in python then `[x[o] for x in a]` will work.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a for loop. You can loop through the list of tuples and add each element to an empty string variable

```
x = [('tore'), ('ngaming'), ('sittam')]
z = ""
for i in x:
    z = z + i + " "

print z
```

After seeing Lafada's answer, I realized that list comprehension and `str.join` is the best option. Though his answer is better, this is basically what his answer does, just done more manually.